# "some of the associated records were not loaded" but they are

Tags: ember.js

I use Ember.js in something of an untraditional way, where I prefer to load everything I could want in my routes, and then switch my relationships to `async: false`

However, I've recently run into a peculiar issue, where I am updating a relationship on a model, then pushing the updated record into the store. In most cases, it works, but in this case I'm getting the "some of the associated records were not loaded" error, which is particularly bizzare, since they are *definitely* loaded.

It seems like ember.js just isn't linking them up properly during the store.push? Does anyone have any insights?

Some more context:

```
store.peekRecord('model-that-im-pushing-into-store', 51).get('relatedToPushedModel')
index.js:139 Uncaught EmberError {stack: "Error: Assertion Failed: You looked up the 'report…ssets/vendor.js:54130:34)↵    at <anonymous>:1:45", 
(anonymous) @ VM594:1

store.peekRecord('model-that-im-pushing-into-store', 51).belongsTo('relatedToPushedModel').id()
"85"

store.peekRecord('related-to-pushed-model', '85').get('name')
"I am definitely loaded"
```

Comment: I don't suppose you could reproduce this in an Ember Twiddle or a repo?

Comment: yeah, having some trouble recreating it, I'm on 2.18, and it works fine in the twiddle. I'm probably going to end up sniffing around the source code to see where this should be happening and isn't. 

I can say that I get an error as soon as a do a `store.push`